# Changing grounds during start up

Tags: can, ground-loop, bms, isolated

We have a system with a CANBUS controlled Battery Management System (BMS) and a PCB with microcontroller. The BMS provides 12V and an isolated CAN ground at all times, but naturally only supplies main battery voltage (and associated ground) when the output is engaged.
To start our system up, we use the 12v and isolated ground to power the microcontroller until it can wake the BMS fully and turn on the main battery output. At that point we need to switch to powering the microcontroller board via the main BMS battery output. In an ideal world, we’d just connect the isolated ground and battery ground together, but for ground loop reasons, we can’t do that.
I’ve inherited this project and as far as I can see, the only way to achieve this is to actively connect the battery ground, then disconnect the isolated CAN ground with relays. There will be a momentary period where they are connected together, but I’m hoping this won’t prove problematic.

I really don’t like this idea, but can’t think of anything else. Has anyone had this sort of issue before in a system?

Comment: "for ground loop reasons we can't do that" You'll have to define this a bit more - what ground loop reasons? The solution you propose does do that, so what reason do you have for thinking that this wont prove problematic?

Comment: Also, one battery but two grounds isn't possible. If you have no separate supply and no external ground, then you _don't_ have isolation by definition.